# Using nextLine and next

Tags: java

I'm having trouble using `nextLine()` to read on a textfile. before, i tried using this kind of text file using `.next()` and it works fine.

```
2
3333
CookingRange
50 450.00 850.00
4444
CircularSaw
150 45.00 125.00
```

Now I want to read input from a file using `nextLine()` to read the line even if it has space between the string.

```
2
3333
Cooking Range
50 450.00 850.00
4444
Circular Saw
150 45.00 125.00
```

And I'm having this kind of error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHfGp.png

So basically my codes look like this

```
public class console {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("items.in"));

        //products

        int itemCount = inFile.nextInt();
        Vector<item> pList = new Vector<item>();

        double totalProfitForItem = 0.0;
        double totalSellingvalueForItem =  0.0;
        double totalAmount = 0.0;
        int totalStock = 0;

        String itemID;
        String itemName;
        int pcsInStore;
        double manufPrice;
        double sellingPrice;
        int j;

        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {

            itemID = inFile.nextLine();
            itemName = inFile.nextLine();
            pcsInStore = inFile.nextInt();
            manufPrice = inFile.nextDouble();
            sellingPrice = inFile.nextDouble();

            item s = new item(itemID, itemName, pcsInStore, manufPrice, sellingPrice, totalSellingvalueForItem, totalProfitForItem);
            pList.addElement(s);

            totalAmount += totalSellingvalueForItem;
            totalStock += pcsInStore;
        }


        for( j = 0; j < pList.size(); j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5s %5s  %5.2f %.2f \n", pList.elementAt(j).getItemID(), pList.elementAt(j).getItemName(), pList.elementAt(j).totsell(), pList.elementAt(j).totprof());
            totalSellingvalueForItem = pList.elementAt(j).totsell();
            totalAmount += totalSellingvalueForItem ;
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Total Amount of Inventory: " + totalAmount +"0");
        System.out.println("Number of Items in the Store: " + totalStock);    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`nextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29)/[`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) reads **only** the `double`/`int` values and doesn't read the `'\n'` that you press after the number is read, so it will be consumed in the [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29).

One solution for this is adding another `nextLine` before the "real" one that will "swallow" the `'\n'` so you can read the actual value in the second `nextLine`.

Regarding the [`InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), this:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type

Could be the result of `'\n'` being read in `nextInt` or `nextDouble` because of what is mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

[`nextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) and [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) only read the double or int values, respectively, but will ignore the invisible "\n" at the end of each line. So when you move on to read the next item, it'll try reading the "\n" as an int or double, causing the `InputMismatchException`. A solution is to execute `.nextLine()` after you read a number and throw away that value (don't store it in an variable) in order to read the "\n" and ignore it in the future.